# Error when installing IPC Bridge for ROS and MatLAB

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install IPC Bridge using a step-by-step guide from this link:
[https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge#Installation](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge#Installation)

After compiling ipc_bridge_ros (rosmake ipc_bridge_ros) and compiling the first message folder (roscd ipc_roslib && make), I'm getting error messages for the remaining folders.

$ roscd ipc_std_msgs && make

std_msgs_Bool_publisher.cc:(.text._ZN3ros13serialization10SerializerIhE4readINS0_7IStreamEEEvRT_Rh[void ros::serialization::Serializer::readros::serialization::IStream(ros::serialization::IStream&, unsigned char&)]+0x3a): undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [std_msgs_Bool_publisher] Error 1

How may I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45838/error-when-installing-ipc-bridge-for-ros-and-matlab/) by [josemscnogueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3383/josemscnogueira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2378/jjamp/) on 2012-10-17**:
It worked for me with Electric, but now I have the same problem with Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04. Any suggestions? Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably not a nice solution but it works for me: Change the last line in ipc_bridge_ros.mk to

```
$(CXX) -I./include $(ROS_CXXFLAGS) $(IPC_BRIDGE_CXXFLAGS) -lstdc++ $(IPC_LFLAGS) -lipc $(ROS_LFLAGS) $(ROS_LIBS) $^ -o bin/$@ -lroscpp -lrosconsole -lroscpp_serialization -lipc
```

---

Originally posted by [jjamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2378/jjamp/) with karma: 58 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4